# <png.h> not found in mac os X mavericks

Tags: c, xcode, macos, png, libpng

I tried (apparently successfully) to install `libpng` on mac os x mavericks.

I downloaded the latest 1-6-8 version `.tar.xz` and followed the instructions.

`./configure` runs fine

`make check` passes everything but png-error that gets skipped

`sudo make install` apparently works fine since my library libpng. appears.

Now, when i try to compile the C file that i need to compile, using the string

`clang -w -lz -lpng16 libpng_test.c`

i get the error

`fatal error: 'png.h' file not found`

`#include <png.h>`

and obviously it does not compile.

I tried installing both with homebrew and macports and it always seems to run fine, but i always get the same error

Comment: "-lz" should follow "-lpng16" on your compile command.  Not sure that is the explanation for your issue though.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First you have to find where the png.h file is located

```
sudo find / -name png.h
```

Here in my environment it is located at **/usr/local/include**

Then look for libpng.a

```
sudo find / -name libpng.a
```

Here in my environment it is located at **/usr/local/lib**

Now add those directories to the clang command line:

```
clang -I/usr/local/include -L/usr/local/lib -w -lz -lpng16 libpng_test.c
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. 

In the end i managed to use openCV which, i discoverd later, was more suitable for my needs :)

Comment: Where is libpng_test.c?

Comment: How to do the same but using `g++-8`?

Comment: Wouldn't recommend using sudo here