# Clang++ not finding png.h during compile

Tags: c++, macos, makefile, homebrew, libpng

I have tried the suggestions in this link with no luck.

[<png.h> not found in mac os X mavericks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20954719/png-h-not-found-in-mac-os-x-mavericks)

I am currently running **OS X 10.11.3** and am using `homebrew` to install all the packages I need and my `libpng` has the same paths as the link above.

I installed `libpng` and `zlib` but when running my `makefile` with `clang++` and `-lpng` I get the error

> png.h file not found

I am not sure how to link `png.h` with the compiler without having to add extra flags in the `makefile` (I don't want to do this because my university uses `svn` and the `makefile` has to work on my personal computer and our linux workstations which don't need the extra flags).

Any advice is appreciated.

Comment: If it can't find `png.h` the problem is not linking but rather the `include file search path`. Homebrew will have installed in `/usr/local/Cellar/libpng/somewhere`, so go in your Build Settings and add the `Include/Header search path` as `/usr/local/Cellar/libpng` **with the recursive option**.- i.e. with double asterisks

Comment: See the blue box on this answer for where you need to make changes... http://stackoverflow.com/a/34341219/2836621